# Why isn't self being automatically passed to a method that is set on an object after its instantiation?

Tags: python

```
 class Person():
    pass;
 def say_hi(self):
    print 'hii'

 me=Person()
 me.say_hi=say_hi
 me.say_hi()
```

Isn't the self argument automatically passed in python ? why why is calling `me.say_hi()` is giving a stack trace ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: say_hi() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(This can act as some demonstration for aaronasterling's answer.)

Here are the definitions:

```
>>> class Person(object):
...     def bound(self):
...             print "Hi, I'm bound."
... 
>>> def unbound(self):
...     print "Hi, I'm unbound."
...
```

Note the types of these methods and functions.

```
>>> type(Person.bound)
<type 'instancemethod'>
>>> type(Person().bound)
<type 'instancemethod'>
>>> type(unbound)
<type 'function'>
>>> Person.unbound = unbound
```

When it gets set on the `Person` before instantiation, it gets bound.

```
>>> Person().bound()
Hi, I'm bound.
>>> Person().unbound()
Hi, I'm unbound.
```

However, if it's set *after* instantiation, it's still of type 'function'.

```
>>> me = Person()
>>> me.rebound = unbound
>>> type(me.rebound)
<type 'function'>
>>> type(me.unbound)
<type 'instancemethod'>
>>> me.rebound
<function unbound at 0x7fa05efac9b0>
>>> me.rebound()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

The 'instancemethod' type can be used to bind a 'function' to an object. It's in the `types` module as `MethodType`.

```
>>> import types
>>> me.rebound = types.MethodType(unbound, me, Person)
```

Now it's bound properly.

```
>>> type(me.rebound)
<type 'instancemethod'>
>>> me.rebound()
Hi, I'm unbound.
>>> # Not true any more!
```

Comment: +1. It's worth noting that the `instancemethod` type has been done away with in Python 3 and the equivalent application of `type` will simply say `function` like in your `unbound` example. Functionally, there's little (I want to say no) difference between an `instancemethod` and a `function`.in Python 2.x for new-style classes. I don't know anything about old-style classes.

Comment: I consciously avoided touching old-style classes. They're evil. I've never tried any of this sort of stuff in Python 3. (Come to think of it, I've never actually *used* post-init method binding, just know about it because it's Good Form to Know about such Things.)

Answer (score 14):

It's not passed in the way that you are doing it.

You would have to do.

```
import types

me.say_hi = types.MethodType(say_hi, me, Person)
```

for it to work.

When python instantiates a class, it essentially carries out the above procedure for each of the class methods. When you 'monkey-patch' a method onto an object in the way that you were trying to do it, it's not a *bound* method and just exists as a function in `instance.__dict__`. Calling it is no different than calling any other function. If you want to stick a method on an instance, you have to manually make it a method as shown above.

If you were to do

```
class Person(object):
    pass

def say_hi(self):
    print 'hii'

Person.say_hi = say_hi

me = Person()
me.say_hi()
```

then it would work because Python will create the method for you.

---

Chris Morgan put up an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267459/python-oo-misunderstanding/4267590#4267590) that shows this one in action. It's good stuff.

Comment: Good answer. I've also added an explanation-by-interactive-console answer to go with this.

Comment: @Chris Morgan. Excellent Answer.

Answer (score 3):

In this case say_hi is not method of your class. It is just reference to a function. This is why the self argument is not passed automatically.

Or just use:

```
class Person():

    def say_hi(self):
       print 'hii'

me=Person() me.say_hi=say_hi me.say_hi()
```

Answer (score 1):

The self argument of a method is passed automatically. You don't have a method, but a function that is an attribute of an object. If you did `Person.say_hi = say_hi`, then Person().say_hi() would work as expected. A method is a function that's attribute of a class, not an instance, and self is passed only for methods.

Class attributes define how the instances should work, while instance attributes are just normal you access. This means that class attributes are modified when they are accessed from an instance (e.g. functions are turned into methods), while instance attributes are left unchanged.

```
>>> class A(object): pass
... 
>>> def f(self): print self
... 
>>> ob = A()
>>> A.f = f
>>> ob.g = f
>>> print ob.f
<bound method A.f of <__main__.A object at 0xb74204ec>>
>>> print ob.g
<function f at 0xb7412ae4>
>>> ob.f()
<__main__.A object at 0xb74204ec>
>>> ob.g('test')
test
```

Since `A` is a class, `f`, `A().f` and `A.f` are different things. Since `ob` is an object, `f` and `ob.g` are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

because the function `say_hi()` wasn't defined inside of the person class it doesn't know what `self` is, and when you call it it isn't passing `self` to the method.  This would be like calling a static method.

you could do this though

```
me=Person()
me.say_hi=say_hi
me.say_hi(me)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, self is not automatically passed to the object, because it has not been defined within the class block. Instead, you have defined a function, say_hi, in the wrong block. When you run it, 'self' in this context, is actually the first parameter of a function which is outside the class block, and therefore not a part of the class, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

i think you wanted to do this

```
say_hi(me)
```

but the usual way to program OO is this:

```
class Person:
   def say_hi(self):
      print 'hii'

me = Person()
me.say_hi()
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this works?

```
class Person():
 def say_hi(self):
  print 'hii'
me=Person()
me.say_hi()
```

I put the function inside the class because I feel thats what you wanted. Then you can call it later from the class object me.